# Is it really better to use async-pipe instead of subscribe() in this particular situation?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

In my component I get an Observable as an @Input().

If the value of the Observable changes, I have to expand/collapse an ng-bootstrap accordion. So I don't really need the Observable's value in the template.

This is the code, I already have:

Component:

```
@Input() urlParam$!: Observable<string>;

@ViewChild('acc') accordion!: NgbAccordion;

urlParamChange$!: Observable<string>;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.urlParamChange$ = this.urlParam$.pipe(
    tap(urlParam => this.synchronizeAccordion(urlParam))
  );
}

synchronizeAccordion(urlParam: string): void {
// do something with this.accordion
}
```

And in the template I subscribe via async pipe to the newly created urlParamChange$:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(urlParamChange$ | async)"></ng-container>

<ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion">
 ....
</ngb-accordion>
```

Since I don't really need the value of the urlParamChange$, I put it in an own ng-container, so that is completely independent, but nevertheless the method for synchronizing the accordion will be called.

I think, that the above implementation isn't that nice. You split the action into two different files (the tap in the component is needed + additionally the async-pipe in the template).

Wouldn't it be even nicer in the following way?
Instead of subscribing with the help of the async-pipe, I will subscribe() directly in the ngAfterViewInit() instead. In that way I can remove the additional variable urlParamChange$ and the implementation is all in the ngAfterViewInit() method.

Component:

```
@Input() urlParam$!: Observable<string>;

@ViewChild('acc') accordion!: NgbAccordion;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.urlParam$.subscribe(urlParam => this.synchronizeAccordion(urlParam));
}

synchronizeAccordion(urlParam: string): void {
// do something with this.accordion
}
```

And in the template the additional ng-container gets removed:

```
<ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion">
 ....
</ngb-accordion>
```

In my opinion both implementations should work exactly in the same way. According to Best Practises, the first solution should be prefered, I would think. But the second one is cleaner IMO.

So what is the best way for implementing such a use case?

Comment: I think you're right. Has someone told you to do the other way?

Comment: No I'm not so experienced nowadays, so I'm not sure which one to use. So solution #1 is the prefered way?

Comment: Is it ok, to use a "dummy ng-container" as I did? Which has no real sense, only to subscribe to the observable via the async pipe?

Comment: I meant the second one, the one you thought was cleaner. The only reason it is a "best practice" to use the async pipe is because you don't have to unsubscribe manually so it usually becomes cleaner. But if, as in your case, it doesn't make it cleaner, you should probably go with the manual subscribe/unsubscribe implementation. What is and what is not a "best practice" is always an opinion and nothing to follow religiously. Understand the reasons behind the best practice, and if it doesn't make sense in your situation, don't follow it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you go with approach 2. Through your own admissions it seems cleaner and easier to follow.

Imagine someone comes along in the future and they see a random `ng-container` with an `async` binding but no content. They may well decide to remove it assuming it is no longer used, in which case your entire `tap` operation will no longer run & no errors will be thrown to alert you to this.

Whereas someone reading through approach 2 can very easily see what is happening and the results of modifying the subscription are apparent.

There is nothing wrong with unsubscribing manually, you just need to make sure you do it!

Answer (score -1):

Why do you call first solution "best practices"? In your case there is no sense in it, use #2.

Comment: Because with the first solution he does not need to unsubscribe manually

Comment: Exactly, with #2 I need to unsubscribe manually.

Comment: And I would say it is following the best practises if you have not to unsubscribe manually.

Comment: to avoid manual unsubscription you suggest to 1) introduce another one observable 2) subscribe to it with async pipe in template. harming readability was never considered as best practicve.